# Efficient ways of array slicing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, slice

I currently have a 2 9x9 arrays where I'm interested in converting the values along its diagonal & off-diagonals into a 9x3 array. To approach this problem, I'm treating this array as a 3x3 "block" array where each "block" is a 3x3 array. To obtain the values that I want to look for, I using either a: 1) for loop or 2) list comprehensions as shown:

```
import numpy as np
ar1 = np.arange(0,81).reshape(9,9)
ar2 = np.arange(81,162).reshape(9,9)

ar1_diag = np.zeros((9,3),dtype = float)
ar2_diag = np.zeros((9,3),dtype = float)

#Method 1: for loop
for i in range(0,3):
    ar1_diag[3*i:3*i+3,:] = ar1[3*i:3*i+3,3*i:3*i+3]
    ar2_diag[3*i:3*i+3,:] = ar2[3*i:3*i+3,3*i:3*i+3]

#Method 2: list comprehension   
ar1_diag2 = np.array([ar1[3*j:3*j+3,3*j:3*j+3] for j in range(0,3)]).reshape(9,3)
ar2_diag2 = np.array([ar2[3*j:3*j+3,3*j:3*j+3] for j in range(0,3)]).reshape(9,3)
```

The list comprehension method seems to have a marginal performance speed benefit over its for loop counterpart if we're considering only using 1 array, but I eventually will have to consider numerous arrays that are much larger than the ones used above.

My question: is there a more efficient/less time consuming way to slice through an array than what I've done (either through map, lambda functions, etc.), or are these method(s) as good as it gets for array slicing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "most" efficient way, but this shows significant improvement-

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit

ar1 = np.arange(0,81).reshape(9,9)
ar2 = np.arange(81,162).reshape(9,9)

ar1_diag = np.zeros((9,3),dtype = float)
ar2_diag = np.zeros((9,3),dtype = float)

ar1_diag2 = np.zeros((9,3),dtype = float)
ar2_diag2 = np.zeros((9,3),dtype = float)

ar1_diag3 = np.zeros((9,3),dtype = float)
ar2_diag3 = np.zeros((9,3),dtype = float)

#Method 1: for loop
def method1():
  global ar1_diag, ar2_diag
  for i in range(0,3):
      ar1_diag[3*i:3*i+3,:] = ar1[3*i:3*i+3,3*i:3*i+3]
      ar2_diag[3*i:3*i+3,:] = ar2[3*i:3*i+3,3*i:3*i+3]

print("Method 1:", timeit.timeit(method1))
# Method 1: 9.25558645000001

#Method 2: list comprehension
ls = [ar1[3*j:3*j+3,3*j:3*j+3] for j in range(0,3)]   
def method2():
  global ar1_diag2, ar2_diag2
  ar1_diag2 = np.array(ls).reshape(9,3)
  ar2_diag2 = np.array(ls).reshape(9,3)

print("Method 2:", timeit.timeit(method2))
# Method 2: 8.4278298549998

#Method 3: array indexing

mask = np.full_like(ar1, False)
for i in range(0,3):
    mask[3*i:3*i+3,3*i:3*i+3] = True
get = np.nonzero(mask)

def method3():
    global ar1_diag3, ar2_diag3
    ar1_diag3 = ar1[get].reshape((9,3))
    ar2_diag3 = ar2[get].reshape((9,3))

print("Method 3:", timeit.timeit(method3))
# Method 3: 4.541714375000083
```

and to make sure that the results are as required

```py
(ar1_diag == ar1_diag2).all() and (ar1_diag == ar1_diag3).all()
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you repeat this many times, it must be more efficient to have a predefined index to slice. In the following code, the variable `index` will be identified as `ar1_diag`, and you can use `np.take_along_axis` to get `ar*_diag`, but it was slow.

```
# Generate 1d index
matrix_number = np.arange(0,81, dtype=np.int).reshape(9,9)
indices = np.repeat(np.arange(0,9).reshape((3,3)), 3, axis=0)
index = np.take_along_axis(matrix_number, indices, axis=1).flatten()

# Target matrix without reshape
ar1_flat = np.arange(0,81)
ar2_flat = np.arange(81,162)

# Output
ar1_diag = ar1_flat[index].reshape((9,3))
ar2_diag = ar2_flat[index].reshape((9,3))
```

### Performance

| Method | %%time it |
| --- | --- |
| Method 1: for loop | 6.87 µs ± 265 ns per loop |
| Method 2: list comprehension | 7.57 µs ± 162 ns per loop |
| Method 3: np.take_along_axis | 18.7 µs ± 682 ns per loop |
| Method 4: Proposed above | 3.15 µs ± 36.3 ns per loop |

Note: If you go for Method 3, the code is as below

```
ar2_diag3 = np.take_along_axis(ar2, indices , axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could prepare a list of flattened indexes and use indirection to get the values in one operation later on:

Setup:

```
bSize = 3
side  = bSize * bSize
h  = np.arange(side).reshape(1, bSize,1, bSize)
v  = np.arange(side).reshape(bSize,1, bSize,1)
m  = v * side + h
flatDiag1 = m[np.identity(bSize,dtype=np.bool)].reshape(side, bSize)
flatDiag2 = m[np.identity(bSize,dtype=np.bool)[:,::-1]].reshape(side, bSize)
```

Usage:

```
print(ar2.flatten()[flatDiag1])

[[ 81  82  83]
 [ 90  91  92]
 [ 99 100 101]
 [111 112 113]
 [120 121 122]
 [129 130 131]
 [141 142 143]
 [150 151 152]
 [159 160 161]]

print(ar2.flatten()[flatDiag2])

[[ 87  88  89]
 [ 96  97  98]
 [105 106 107]
 [111 112 113]
 [120 121 122]
 [129 130 131]
 [135 136 137]
 [144 145 146]
 [153 154 155]]
```

Note that flatDiag1 is the same as ar1_diag and ar1_diag2 so you can use what you already have but store these matrices in a central place for reuse as indexes for indirection.

If you need to access a specific block, you can also use the `m` matrix as an indirection mechanism:

```
print(ar2.flatten()[m[2,2]]) # block (2,2) in block coordinates

[[141 142 143]
 [150 151 152]
 [159 160 161]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ar1_diag2` without the reshape is:

```
Out[87]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [18, 19, 20]],

       [[30, 31, 32],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [48, 49, 50]],

       [[60, 61, 62],
        [69, 70, 71],
        [78, 79, 80]]])
```

Looking at `ar1` test are 3 (3,3) blocks from `ar1`:

```
In [89]: ar1
Out[89]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
       [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
       [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]])
```

We can use `as_strided` to reshape that into a (3,3,3,3) array.  (`as_strided` is oven suggested as a way of getting moving windows, especially overlapping ones):

```
In [90]: X = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(ar1,shape=(3,3,3,3),strides=(9*3*8,
    ...: 3*3*8,3*8,8))
In [91]: X
Out[91]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8]],

        [[ 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17]],
        ....
```

I can select the desired diagonal blocks from this:

```
In [92]: X[np.arange(3),:,np.arange(3)]
Out[92]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [18, 19, 20]],

       [[30, 31, 32],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [48, 49, 50]],

       [[60, 61, 62],
        [69, 70, 71],
        [78, 79, 80]]])
```

Initially I tried `X[np.arange(3),np.arange(3)]` but that was the wrong diagonal.  I suspect this would work if I used different set of strides in the `as_strided`. (`strides=(9*3*8,3*8,3*3*8,8)` is the right strides.)

While `as_strided` creates a `view` and can be a big help when creating large moving windows, it isn't always fastest. Here is looses:

```
In [96]: timeit ar1_diag2 = np.array([ar1[3*j:3*j+3,3*j:3*j+3] for j in range(0,3)])
8.7 µs ± 24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [97]: timeit X = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(ar1,shape=(3,3,3,3),
     strides=(9*3*8,3*3*8,3*8,8))[np.arange(3),:,np.arange(3)]
26 µs ± 1.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

### edit

I just realized that my first use of `as_strided` was just a `reshape(3,3,3,3)`.  That is, the strides were the same.  That means we can use

```
In [115]: timeit ar1.reshape(3,3,3,3)[np.arange(3),:,np.arange(3)]
8.7 µs ± 236 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

That's the same time as your `ar1_diag2` indexing.